# how to get class instances out of a dict in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a class `Collection' that looks like this:

```
class Collection():

    def __init__(self, db, collection_name):
        self.db = db
        self.collection_name = collection_name

        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'client'):
            self.__class__.client = MongoClient()

        self.data_base = getattr(self.client, self.db)
        self.collection = getattr(self.data_base, self.collection_name)

    def getCollectionKeys(self):
    ....etc.
```

I cleverly created a function to create a dictionary of class instances as follows:

```
def getCollections():
    collections_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(db_collection_names)):
        collections_dict[db_collection_names[i]] = Collection(database_name, db_collection_names[i])
    return collections_dict
```

it works.  however, whenever I want to access a class instance, I have to go through the dictionary:

```
agents_keys = collections_dict['agents'].getCollectionKeys()
```

I would love to just write:

```
agents_keys = agents.getCollectionKeys()
```

Is there a simple way to get those instances "out" of the dict?

Comment: `agents = collections_dict['agents']` ?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso is there a way to run that for all the dict items so i don't have to type them out individually?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to items in a vanilla python dictionary using a generator object in a for loop, or by using a list expression.

```
 agent_keys = [x.getCollectionKeys() for x in collections_dict.values()]
```

or this

```
 agent_keys = []
 for name in db_collection_names:
    #do something with individual item
    #there could also be some logic here about which keys to append
    agent_keys.append(collections_dict[name].getCollectionKeys())

#now agent_keys is full of all the keys
```

My mental model of how objects are interacted with in python. Feel free to edit if you actually know how it works.

> You cannot "take" items of the dictionary per say unless you call the `del`  operator which removes the association of a variable name (that is what you type in the editor like "foo" and "bar") with an object ( the actual collections of bits in the program your machine sees). What you can do is get a reference to the object, which in python is a symbol that for all your intents and purposes **is** the object you want.

The dictionary just holds a bunch of references to your database objects.
The expression `collections_dict['agents']` is equivalent to your original database object that you put into the dictionary like this 
`collections_dict['agents'] = my_particular_object`

Comment: the values of `collections_dict` are `Collection` instances,  your `individual_item` contains both key and value

Comment: @haifzhan I flipped them in my head, thanks for the catch. If you see such bad errors, feel free to edit.

Comment: @Karl Thanks for the answer!  I guess I'm asking if I can run a loop such that all the collections are available via the appropriate variable.  More specifically, is there a way to create a loop version of `agents = collections_dict['agents']`?

Comment: @dwstein Are you saying you have a list of keys, and that 'agents' is just one key? and you want to be able to acess specific collections objects given some strings that describe the key? Or is `agent_keys` all of the keys total for all of the objects in the `collections_dict`. If it is all then it is easy, just some then you need to know somehow which dictionary keys you want to access

Comment: @Karl  I'm not entirely sure.  When accessing individual class instances, I would like to be able to just use `agents.ClassMethod` as opposed to `collections_dict['agents'].ClassMethod`.

Comment: @dwstein is `agents` a singleton that refers to an entire dictionary or do you have multiple variables like `agent1` and `agent2` .... such that you want `agent1.ClassMethod` to map to `collections_dict["agents1"].ClassMethod`, Also, do these `agents` already exist or do you want to create them in the loop so latter you can just type `agents` in your code and know that the appropriate thing is there?

Comment: @Karl the agents exist.  this is all going to be read-only access to the database for reporting.

Comment: so for each variable in `db_collection_names` is there a variable that must be able to call class methods, or is there a singleton `agents`?